# System.Management.dll not being copied to output directory .net 6 c#

Tags: dll, system, .net-6.0

There is an error `System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Management, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified.'`.I figured when the System.Management.dll is in the output directory, the error will be gone.

It is reference using NuGet but I couldn't get libraries in NuGet to be copied to the output folder. So I thought of adding the physical System.Management.dll file into my project and and reference it as assemblies (right-click project -> Add Reference -> browse to library) thenset 'Copy Local' to True. However, the dll still won't get copied over to the output folder.

The application is on .Net 6. Is there a reason behind why I can't copy this library like other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out I could copy nuget package references to output directory by setting this attribute in the project file

```
<CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
```

Then the nuget referenced packages will be copied to the output directory.

Answer (score 0):

A .NET6 project would normally use System.Management version 6.0.0.

The error suggests that there is another package in your project that explicitly depends on 4.0.0.

Without knowing the specifics of you projects,  I suggest:

- inspecting the build output for warnings about package version,
- upgrading 3rd party packages in your solution.